# Modifying the babel French spacing for punctuations

Tags: babel-french

I'm writing French with typewriter font, and the default auto-spacing for punctuations provided by `babel` is a little unsatisfactory.

[image]

(the above one is in French mode, the bottom one is in English mode)

I need the space before punctuations to be exactly one whitespace. How can I modify this value?

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\ttdefault}
\raggedright

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french}
Qu'est-ce que c'est ? C'est ...

\selectlanguage{english}
Qu'est-ce que c'est ? C'est ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what you've tried so far.

Comment: A small example to play with?

Comment: @egreg I just added a MWE. The one in English is the effect I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code for `?` removes a possible space before it and then adds `\FBthinspace`, which is defined as

```
\hskip 0.5\fontdimen2\font\relax
```

but what you want is the full `\fontdimen2\font`. On the other hand, the colon uses `\FBcolonspace`, which is defined as `\space`, so the full solution is to make the two macros do the same.

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{\ttdefault}
\raggedright

\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

\renewcommand{\FBthinspace}{\FBcolonspace}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{french}
Qu'est-ce que c'est ? C'est; c'est: c'est! ...

\selectlanguage{english}\frenchspacing
Qu'est-ce que c'est ? C'est ; c'est : c'est ! ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the English part used for comparison, I set `\frenchspacing` to avoid the extra space after punctuation being added.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that babel-french *does not* modify the spacing before high punctuation when the font is *declared* as mono-spaced ("Typewriter").

In your example, you *declare* you are working with \rmfamily, that's why you get a thin space before the `?'. @egreg provided the right patch.

If you add \ttfamily after the \begin{document} in @egreg's example (removing the `\renewcommand{\FBthinspace}`), you will note that the space before '?' is what you want (inter-word space), but don't be surprised to get no space before ':' and '!' as none is present in the source code.